# write json data from hive to local file

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

This is my query in hive

```
select colname from uber_test;
OK
{"data":"{\"age\":42, \"gender\":\"male\"}"}
```

This is how I export data:

```
    CREATE TABLE export_test_1( name STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
    INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY 'export_test_1' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' select colname from uber_test;
```

This is what my data looks like after I export:

```
more export_test_2/000000_0 
data{"age":42, "gender":"male"}
```

I need to preserve the json. needs to be:

```
 {"data":"{\"age\":42, \"gender\":\"male\"}"}
```

Comment: is colname type string and contains string as json?